# angular4 project backup and move

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have angular4 project made by angular-cli on window. I would like to move this project to new ubuntu machine. I already installed angular-cli on new machine. should I move whole project file? If then, everything will work fine? any one have done this before?

Comment: It should work.

Comment: You wouldn't need to copy the node_modules folder. You can pretty much copy everything else to the new machine and run npm install. Everything should work as normal

Comment: Try to use git or svn for code storing/versioning/sharing. This is very helpful. And then you just need to checkout/update your project in any machine/OS. And don't commit node_modules :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have all relevant things installed on your new location (node, npm, angular/cli, etc. etc.).

Remove the node_modules folder (plus any other non-source folders you may or may not have like bower or whatnot) - unless you *really* want to copy an additional 30k+ files...

Copy/paste the entire (reduced) solution to your desired location.

Treat it like any other solution in any other location -> `npm install` -> `ng serve`.